# how to have a static index column in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have a table like this:

```
idx name    height
1   dan     180
2   steve   175
3   peter   185
4   joe     165
```

when I click the 'height' header, the slickgrid's onSort function will give me a result like this:

```
idx name    height
4   joe     165
2   steve   175
1   dan     180
3   peter   185
```

That is the needs of the most, but I hope I can get this result:

```
idx name    height
1   joe     165
2   steve   175
3   dan     180
4   peter   185
```

This index column is just to let people know the row index, it won't get changed when other columns do sorting.

First time asking questions, sorry if you get confused.

Answer (score 4):

Write a custom formatter:

```
function rowNumFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return row + 1;
}
```

and specify it in the column definition.