# Make Slickgrid columns not sortable

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid table with multiple columns and I want the Index Column to be unaffected from sorting  other columns.

I found [this ancient question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834922/how-to-have-a-static-index-column-in-slickgrid) that is exactly describing the problem I'm having here, but the answer there didn't work for me. When I used this solution, my index column didn't return any values, it was just blank.

I tried if simply using a custom formatter would exlude the column from the sorting process, which it didn't. To do this, I copied "defaultFormatter" from [here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js)

```
function indexFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
if (value == null) {
        return "";
      } else {
        return (value + "").replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
      }
    };
```

PS: I thought it would be good to ask this in a new question rather than reviving the 9 year old one I linked earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest to ignore the index column (this is, after all what SlickGrid uses to look up rows, so you don't want to mess with it) and just use the actual row number.

```
function indexFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return (row + 1) + '';
};
```

EDIT: whoops, I see that is just what the previous answer said too. Nonetheless, he was the creator of SlickGrid and I am one of the current maintainers, so give it a try! You may need the "+ ''" to convert to a string.

Comment: Well, it's not really the same answer. The old one is missing the brackets after the "return". Could that be the reason it didn't work for me? Also, by ignoring the index column, do you mean it's best to leave it out completely? Or is it safe to use the code you provided? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it should work. By 'ignore the index column', I mean that using ```value``` yields the id from the index column which is the internal unique key, generally not meant for humans to see, and will not be in order if sorting has occurred. What you want is simply the index of the row in the grid, and that is ```row```. It is zero based, so we add one to be kind to humans ;-) and we add an empty string to force the numeric value to become a string.

Comment: If only `row` is important, then why do I still have to use `cell, value, columnDef, dataContext` if they aren't relevant?

Comment: That's simply the parameters that are passed to all formatters by the grid. You can do with them what you wish, including doing nothing. Think of them as a set of tools that the formatter template provides you. If you don't need a particular tool, just ignore it. But if you wanted to, you could use ```row``` to make every third row green, or ```datacontext``` to make the row yellow if the value of the third column started with 'c'.